# Represent a set of Strings in unique numbers which can be sorted based on the number as well.

Tags: java, sorting

I am looking for a mechanism in which I can represent a set of strings using unique numbers, so that when I want to sort them I can use the numbers to sort this values.

For eg, this is what I have in mind

I am keeping a fixed length number 20 digits

Each alphabet is represented with its ASCII/some alphabetical order value

cat - (03)(01)(20)(00)(00)(00)(00)(00)(00)(00) - 03012000000000000000
cataract - (03)(01)(20)(01)(18)(01)(03)(20)(00)(00) - 03012001180103200000
capital - (03)(01)(16)(09)(20)(01)(12)(00)(00)(00) - 03011609200112000000

So if I sort it based on the numbers, it will sort and say

capital, cat, cataract

Is this a good way of doing this?

Is there any other way for doing this so that I have more accuracy?

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: Why not just sort the `String`(s)?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: If you only need lexicographic sorting just use a `TreeSet<String>`. The default `Comparator` will do the job for you.

Comment: I was thinking that a O(n) complexity sort mechanism can be written for that if in can represent it in numbers.

Comment: Can't see how you could get anything better than O(log n) if your `String`s aren't sorted in advance.

Comment: @Sen A ["bucket sort"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) would be O(n), but for data like this I believe you would need way too many buckets, far more than could fit into memory.

Comment: @Sen Also look up [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).  If your input strings are limited to 20 characters in length, and you pad each string with spaces to make them 20 characters, this could work.

Comment: @Sen it's mathematically proven than there is no sorting algorithm that can do better then O(n logn) in the worst case scenario.

Comment: @Alboz that only applies to sorting algorithms that work by comparing items, and not to algorithms like pigeonhole/counting/bucket/radix sort.

Answer (score 1):

If your string length is fixed and your character set is fixed to say 100 different characters you could treat each character of your string as a number in a base 100 number to turn the string into a double.

If your set of strings is much smaller than the set of possible strings you could hash them and for collisions define the sort order arbitrarily but consistently.

In a specific case I probably wouldn't recommend either of those, but as a SUPER GENERAL solution to what you stated it works.  But if you ask what seems to be a theoretical question, a theoretical answer seems appropriate.